# add png-image into VHDL documentation

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to add a png image to my Doxygen documentation of VHDL code. I use the following line:

```
--! @image html FW_blocks.png
```

however, no image can be found in the Doxygen output. Is image including even possible with Doxygen-VHDL? if yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

the **code mentioned in the question works**. the problem was an error in the IMAGE_PATH.